# How to grep log file within this hour

Tags: bash, awk

This is a log file (delimiter is space and the date format is written by `$date` command with no arguments):

```
Client1 purchased at Wed Jun 14 10:15:10 +0430 2023
Client2 returned at Wed Jun 14 16:15:10 +0430 2023
Client3 purchased at Sat Jul  8 16:04:31 +0330 2023
Client3 returned (returned all) at Sat Jul  8 20:05:11 +0330 2023
Client4 returned at Sat Jul  8 21:15:19 +0330 2023
```

After July 8th, I added a `(here all)` but not for all of `here`s. In fact `(here all)` is added only once during the day and at an specific time (suppose 16).

So, my expected output and logic:

```
if second column is purchased and it happened during this hour (for example if current hour is 11, it should check only if log's hour is 11), do this.
elif second column is returned and it happened during this hour, do that.
elif second column is returned (returned all) and it happened during this hour, do something else.
```

This is what I suppose to do, but the second `grep` matches only exactly 60 minutes before from now.

```
while read -r line
do
    if [ "$(grep purchased | grep $(date --date='now-60 minutes'))" ]
    then
        awk '{print $1, "purchased"}' # this is for test to only check if prints correctly
    elif [ "$(grep returned | grep $(date --date='now-60 minutes'))" ]
    then
        awk '{print $1, "returned"}' # this is for test to only check if prints correctly
    elif [ "$(grep 'returned (returned all)' | grep $(date --date='now-60 minutes'))" ]
    then
        awk '{print $1, "returned (returned all)"}' # this is for test to only check if prints correctly
    fi
done < log
```

I'm trying to google to check the current hour only but I failed up to now.

Also if matters, I can change the output of `date` from today because I need this `if` clause from today and I don't need the old data of log file.

**Update 1**

This is the issue I have which was not expected to happen:

```
[root@server ~]# date
Tue Jul 11 14:57:15 +0330 2023
[root@server ~]# cat file
Client1 purchased at Wed Jun 14 13:15:10 +0430 2023
Client2 returned at Wed Jun 14 14:15:10 +0430 2023
Client3 purchased at Sat Jul  8 16:04:31 +0330 2023
Client3 returned (returned all) at Sat Jul  11 14:05:11 +0330 2023
Client4 returned at Sat Jul  11 14:15:19 +0330 2023
Client5 returned at July 11 2023 13:15:15
[root@server ~]# bash script.sh
Client2 returned at Wed Jun 14 14:15:10 +0430 2023
Client3 returned (returned all) at Sat Jul  11 14:05:11 +0330 2023
Client4 returned at Sat Jul  11 14:15:19 +0330 2023
```

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem, but grep exits unsuccessfully if it finds no match. So you don't need the square brackets; just do `if grep purchased | grep $(date --date='now-60 minutes'); then...`

Comment: that log format is terrible. Usually time is fixed at the beginning or after some fixed fields so that we can grep quickly with `^time`. Besides using the standard ISO-8601 timestring would make it not only shorter but also self-sorted and much easier to grep

Comment: @phuclv yes you're right. Since I only needed a time, I did the messy way. Thanks for the hint, I'll make the times better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overly complicate matters by mixing `grep` and `awk` when `awk` alone (called once) will do (and be orders of magnitude faster). This solution presumes your data is as shown with the time beginning as the 7th field if not (here all) and as the 9th field if so.

All you need to do is pass `awk` the current hour and minute (create a value for that, e.g. `now = hour * 60 + minute`) and then split the time in log to create a similar value (`tlog`) which is the time in log `hour * 60 + minute`. Now all you need to do is make sure `now - 60 < tlog && tlog < now` to find your log entries that are within the last hour.

(**note:** you will need to add logic to handle to 23:59 to 00:00 day change -- but that is left to you, e.g. check if `h == 0` and use `(h + 24 * 60)` or some similar scheme to handle the change)

The case for the rest of the clock is:

```bash
awk -v h=$(date +%H) -v m=$(date +%M) '     ## get current hour & minute
  BEGIN { now = h * 60 + m }                ## now is hour * 60 + minute
  {
    split (($3=="at") ? $7 : $9, a, ":")    ## split date in log file into a
    tlog = a[1] * 60 + a[2]                 ## tlog is hour * 60 + minute
    if (now - 60 < tlog && tlog < now) {    ## if tlog in last hour
      print                                 ## print record
    }
  }
' file
```

Note the current hour and minute are passed to `awk` via the `-v` option and two command substitutions `$(...)` from the command line. The `($3=="at") ? $7 : $9` is a simple ternary that just says if the 3rd field is `"at"` use `$7` (seventh field) with `split()`, otherwise use `$9` (the ninth field).

See the [GNU Awk User's Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) for explanation of `split()`.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Very nice and descriptive answer thanks for sharing

Comment: Thank you Ravinder. Haven't seen you in a bit. Been slow lately...

Comment: Thanks, but it has one issue: if the time is within last 60 minutes, it doesn't check if the day or month is today. I mean if hour is 15, it checks all hours of 15.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I updated the question with the issue I see as per previous comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My date format is `$(date +'%B %d %Y %H:%M:%S')` and I'm trying to add multiplication of `h * 60 + m * 30 * 12 * 365` but it seems that's not correct. I also added new variables if month, day and year.

Comment: How are you dealing with the time-zone?

Comment: @kvantour are you asking me? That's the `date` of the server and it's NTP, set to Tehran

Comment: @Saeed maybe I understand incorrectly, but if you request the last hour of _purchased_ entries, and you have entries which have a time-stamp with a different time-zone, than it is important to correct for the time-zone.  (eg.  2000-01-01T00:00:00 +0000 and 2000-01-01T00:00:00 +0200 are 2 h apart)

Comment: @kvantour no, all timezones are the same, they're Tehran.

Comment: The `now - 60 < tlog && tlog < now` test ensures that the entries within the last 60 minutes are checked (excluding 60 and 0 [the current minute]) if you want those included, then it's `now - 60 <= tlog && tlog <= now`

Answer (score 1):

[TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr)

```
$ txr -e '
(awk ((if-match `@nil purchased at @nil @date` rec
        (> 3600 (- (time) (time-parse-local "%b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y" date))))))
' log
```

Comment: @Berthold Sorry about the bad URL that had to be deleted; I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk you can process this perfectly. However, you have to take care of the time-zones and time-zone processing is required.
Time-zone handling in awk is done properly, by forcing it by overwriting the `TZ` environment variable. Example. When my local time is UTC, I can compute convert a time of "UTC+03:00" in the following way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ ENVIRON["TZ"]="UTC+03:00";t=mktime("2000 01 01 00 00 00");
              ENVIRON["TZ"]="UTC";      print strftime("%FT%T",t)}'
2000-01-01T03:00:00
```

The second tricky part, is processing the month which is in human readable Format. This is done using this trick:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{monthList="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"; print (index(monthList,"May")+2)/3}'
5
```

Now that the tricky part is done, we can search for the entries of the last 1h. This is best done by checking current time in epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC) which is the output of `mktime`, all we need to do is trick it's time-zone:

```
BEGIN { monthList="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
        currentTime=systime() }
# Skip to the next record if it is not "purchased"
$2 != "purchased" { next }
# Read month, timezone, build string and convert time to UNIX epoch:
{ dateString = $NF " " (index(monthList,$(NF-4))+2)/3 " " $(NF-3) " " $(NF-2)
  gsub("[^0-9]"," ",dateString);
  tz = $(NF-1); tz="UTC"substr(tz,1,3)":"substr(tz,4,2)
  ENVIRON["TZ"] = tz; t=mktime(dateString)
}
# Check if it is less than 1h old, if so, print
( currentTime - t < 3600)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print out the line that occured within a period of one hour or less, you need to parse the time stamp.

The easiest commandline tool to do that is Ruby (for me...):

```
cat file
Client1 purchased at Wed Jun 14 10:15:10 +0430 2023
Client2 returned at Wed Jun 14 16:15:10 +0430 2023
Client3 purchased at Sat Jul  8 16:04:31 +0330 2023
Client3 returned (returned all) at Sat Jul  8 20:05:11 +0330 2023
Client4 returned at Sat Jul  8 21:15:19 +0330 2023
Client4 purchased at Sat Jul  9 11:19:19 -0400 2023
```

(I added the last line there since it is within one hour in the EDT time zone when I did this.)

```
ruby -r time -lane 'puts $_ if ($F[1]=="purchased"  &&
    (Time.now-Time.strptime($_[/(?<=at\s\S\S\S\s).*$/], "%b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y"))<3600)' file
```

Prints:

```
Client4 purchased at Sat Jul  9 11:19:19 -0400 2023
```